my csv file isn't getting updated after hitting submit in pythonanywhere
i have deployed my flask program using pythonanywhere.com
it is an application form
the details submitted are getting updated in the csv file when i run it using idle
but it does not get updated when running it using pythonanywhere
this is the flask_app.py file
from flask import Flask,render_template, request, url_for
import csv
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

# Session configuration

def csv_appender(student_data):
    with open('Application_Details.csv','a+',newline='\n') as csv_file:
        writer_csv=csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer_csv.writerow(student_data)

@app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    if request.method=='POST':
        NameofChild=request.form.get('NameofChild')
        Gender=request.form.get('Gender')
        DOB=request.form.get('DOB')
        StaffChild=request.form.get('StaffChild')
        MotherTongue=request.form.get('MotherTongue')
        Religion=request.form.get('Religion')
        Caste=request.form.get('Caste')
        Nationality=request.form.get('Nationality')
        AadhaarNo=request.form.get('AadhaarNo')
        EMISorSATS=request.form.get('EMISorSATS')
        AdmissionClass=request.form.get('AdmissionClass')
        SchoolLastAttended=request.form.get('SchoolLastAttended')
        LastClassAttended=request.form.get('LastClassAttended')
        MediumOfInstruction=request.form.get('MediumOfInstruction')
        SecondLanguage=request.form.get('SecondLanguage')
        ThirdLanguage=request.form.get('ThirdLanguage')
        MotherName=request.form.get('MotherName')
        FatherName=request.form.get('FatherName')
        MotherMobile=request.form.get('MotherMobile')
        FatherMobile=request.form.get('FatherMobile')
        MotherEmail=request.form.get('MotherEmail')
        FatherEmail=request.form.get('FatherEmail')
        MotherAadhaar=request.form.get('MotherAadhaar')
        FatherAadhaar=request.form.get('FatherAadhaar')
        MotherOccupation=request.form.get('MotherOccupation')
        FatherOccupation=request.form.get('FatherOccupation')
        MotherDesignation=request.form.get('MotherDesignation')
        FatherDesignation=request.form.get('FatherDesignation')
        MotherOrganisation=request.form.get('MotherOrganisation')
        FatherOrganisation=request.form.get('FatherOrganisation')
        MotherOfficeAddress=request.form.get('MotherOfficeAddress')
        FatherOfficeAddress=request.form.get('FatherOfficeAddress')
        MotherAnnualSalary=request.form.get('MotherAnnualSalary')
        FatherAnnualSalary=request.form.get('FatherAnnualSalary')
        MaritalStatus=request.form.get('MaritalStatus')
        ResidentialAddress=request.form.get('ResidentialAddress')
        PINCode=request.form.get('PINCode')
        City=request.form.get('City')
        State=request.form.get('State')
        ResidentialPhoneNo=request.form.get('ResidentialPhoneNo')
        EmergencyPhoneNo=request.form.get('EmergencyPhoneNo')
        CommunicationEmail=request.form.get('CommunicationEmail')
        KnowAboutSchool=request.form.get('KnowAboutSchool')
        Distance=request.form.get('Distance')
        ModeOfTransport=request.form.get('ModeOfTransport')
        AnyAilment=request.form.get('AnyAilment')
        Ailment=request.form.get('Ailment')
        SiblingInSchool=request.form.get('SiblingInSchool')
        S1Name=request.form.get('S1Name')
        S1Age=request.form.get('S1Age')
        S1Gender=request.form.get('S1Gender')
        S1Class=request.form.get('S1Class')
        S1USN=request.form.get('S1USN')
        S2Name=request.form.get('S2Name')
        S2Age=request.form.get('S2Age')
        S2Gender=request.form.get('S2Gender')
        S2Class=request.form.get('S2Class')
        S2USN=request.form.get('S2USN')
        S3Name=request.form.get('S3Name')
        S3Age=request.form.get('S3Age')
        S3Gender=request.form.get('S3Gender')
        S3Class=request.form.get('S3Class')
        S3USN=request.form.get('S3USN')
        S4Name=request.form.get('S4Name')
        S4Age=request.form.get('S4Age')
        S4Gender=request.form.get('S4Gender')
        S4Class=request.form.get('S4Class')
        S4USN=request.form.get('S4USN')
        csv_appender([NameofChild, Gender, DOB, StaffChild, MotherTongue, Religion, Caste, Nationality, AadhaarNo, EMISorSATS, AdmissionClass, SchoolLastAttended, LastClassAttended, 'English', SecondLanguage, ThirdLanguage, MotherName, FatherName, MotherMobile, FatherMobile, MotherEmail, FatherEmail, MotherAadhaar, FatherAadhaar, MotherOccupation, FatherOccupation, MotherDesignation, FatherDesignation, MotherOrganisation, FatherOrganisation, MotherOfficeAddress, FatherOfficeAddress, MotherAnnualSalary, FatherAnnualSalary, MaritalStatus, ResidentialAddress, PINCode, City, State, ResidentialPhoneNo, EmergencyPhoneNo, CommunicationEmail, KnowAboutSchool, Distance, ModeOfTransport, AnyAilment, Ailment, SiblingInSchool, S1Name, S1Age, S1Gender, S1Class, S1USN, S2Name, S2Age, S2Gender, S2Class, S2USN,S3Name,S3Age, S3Gender, S3Class, S3USN, S4Name, S4Age, S4Gender, S4Class, S4USN])
        return render_template('submitted.html')
    return render_template('start.html')

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=False,host='0.0.0.0')
    #from waitress import serve
    #serve(app,host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)s

directory -> 
what should i do for it to get updated?

so i found the error
pythonanywhere was trying to find the csv file in the folder where the mysite folder is located in
it basically created the csv file there and stored data it that file rather than saving it in the original file which is located inside the mysite folder
i simply deleted the the original one that i created and just added the headings to the csv file that pythonanywhere created
